# T-SQL alias from CASE statement in SELECT clause not recognized in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

Why does the first query work, but not the second?  Why doesn't the alias get recognized when using the CASE statement?  How can I fix the second query so the WHERE clause works?

```
SELECT
[a],
[b],
[c],
[d],
[e],
(CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Y WHERE Y.a = X.b AND Y.b IS NOT NULL) > 1 then 1 else 0 END) Q
FROM X
--WHERE Q = 1

SELECT
[a],
[b],
[c],
[d],
[e],
(CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Y WHERE Y.a = X.b AND Y.b IS NOT NULL) > 1 then 1 else 0 END) Q
FROM X
WHERE Q = 1
```

**Error for 2nd query:**

```
Invalid column name 'Q'
```

Comment: Please read "Logical Processing Order of the Select Statement" from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189499.aspx): "because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses" `WHERE` is step 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct behavior.  If you want to use the alias in the `where` clause, use a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT X.*
FROM (SELECT [a], [b], [c], [d], [e],
             (CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Y WHERE Y.a = X.b AND Y.b IS NOT NULL) > 1 then 1 else 0
              END) Q
      FROM X
     ) X
WHERE Q = 1;
```

Comment: you could also factor out just the `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Y WHERE Y.a = X.b AND Y.b IS NOT NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

A column alias cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause unless it is introduced in the `FROM` clause. Either repeat the whole expression or put the `SELECT` in a CTE and then work with the CTE to use the alias.

Comment: Incorrect, or at least incomplete. A column alias introduced within the `FROM` clause can be used in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer to include your point.